# Parameterized query using node-postgres isn't passed between quotes

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm using the npm module `pg` with Node.js, and have the following query:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM territories WHERE '($1, -122.26), (47.57, -122.36)'::box \ 
         @> point(nwlat, nwlng) ORDER BY nwlat, nwlng;"
client.query(query, [lat+.05], callback);
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

`invalid input syntax for type box: "($1, -122.26), (47.57, -122.36)"`

But when I replace `$1` with a decimal literal, like `47.67`, it executes normally. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that this:

```
'$1'
```

doesn't have a placeholder in it, it is a string literal that just happens to contain some characters that look like a numbered placeholder. So this:

```
'($1, -122.26), (47.57, -122.36)'
```

doesn't have a placeholder either, that's just a string literal that happens to contain the characters `$` and `1`. Consider the difference between this:

```
let x = 6;
let y = 'x'; // String that contains the name of a variable.
```

and this:

```
let x = 6;
let y = x;  // The actual variable itself.
```

in JavaScript, same idea.

You can build your `box` string using string concatenation:

```
WHERE ('(' || $1 || ', -122.26), (47.57, -122.36)')::box
```

but that's not very pretty. A cleaner solution would be to bypass strings and casting altogether by using the [`point` and `box` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-CONV-TABLE):

```
WHERE box(point($1, -122.26), point(47.57, -122.36))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was expecting, but I wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the answer by @mu is too short

With [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) query formatting you would get exactly what you expect ;)